# How is my apache installation loading PHP-FPM

Tags: php, apache

I made a clean `Centos 8` installation where I installed `Apache 2.4` and `php-fpm (remi-8.0)` with this simple line:

```
dnf install -y httpd php-fpm
```

No other code, no other change to the system, nothing.

After starting `httpd.service` and `php-fpm` I can access PHP files using my browser. Great. The problem is this: I know that the configuration file of `PHP-FPM` is at `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf` but I have absolutely no idea how Apache is loading this file. On `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` I see nothing pointing to this file, same in the `conf.modules.d` directory - nothing.

I just want to know how does Apache knows to load `php-fpm`, or does it even know that `php-fpm` is enable and it has to `proxy` the request to PHP interpret the requested file? In many tutorials online people installing `php-fpm` add lots of lines to virtual hosts, to `httpd.conf` file... But I did nothing and it worked. Why?

Comment: As I understand FPM, a.k.a. "PHP FastCGI process manager" is running as service, Apache communicates via socket to FPM. It's running out of box because of default pre-setup. To fit your needs you change config files

Comment: @Justinas thank you! The only thing I cant understand is where, in the default installation, there is any mention to `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf`! Why Apache installation files point to this file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**php-fpm** is a FastCGI service listening on a socket defined in /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf

```
listen = /run/php-fpm/www.sock
```

**httpd** is another service, using [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html) to communicate with it using the socket defined in /etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock|fcgi://localhost"
</FilesMatch>
```

> But I did nothing and it worked. Why?

Because it is designed to work out of the box, thanks to default configuration files provided by the php-fpm package ;)

Comment: PERFECT! I was trying to find that file at `/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d` but it was located at `/etc/httpd/conf.d`! Thank you so much!!!